# How long does an event live in the eventbus?

Tags: java, guava

I would like to @Subscribe a method in a Runnable that is created by a ScheduledFuture, so that I can signal it from another thread whether to run.  Because a ScheduledFuture creates the object at some future time, there is no scope for the @Subscribe listener to pick up my event.  So, I'm wondering how long an event sits in the bus, waiting to picked up by a listener?  Is the actual pub-sub synchronous wrt sending/receiving events or will they sit in a queue for some duration before timing out?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for "sticky" events which are rebroadcast when a new subscriber registers. Guava's event bus does not provide this by default. Am I understanding your use case correctly?

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guava's `EventBus` does not provide sticky events. Additionally, due to the design of `EventBus`, it's not as straightforward as it could be to extend it to implement such a sticky design, as a lot of the internals are package-private (e.g. the logic to discover which methods on a registered object are annotated with `Subscribe` and mapping them to the proper event type).

I do think there are some other libraries out there which do provide this, like GreenRobot's event bus (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), but without introducing a new library you'll have to build it more or less from scratch.

An alternative that I've used is RxJava's `Observables` with a `replay(1)` operator, so that subscribing to the observable will always immediately invoke the subscription callback with the last item, but it's not a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Ditto on RxJava. Exactly what I was going to suggest. That library changed my life even more than Google Guava. It has a learning curve but reactive programming really excels at these kinds of problems.